# Server receive message not in sequence

Tags: asynchronous, server

I am building a messenger system. since it is an async server, the user send message not in order in which it makes the message record stored not in order, i am wondering what I can do without delaying the send time.

Comment: If they're not in order, that implies that order exists. If order exists, that means there's a number that says which message comes at which position. So.. send that number with the message? Luckily, you posted so much code which makes it super easy to help you. Imagine if you hadn't posted any code.

Comment: you can send the timestamp (unix) in the message body, so you could later reorder it